# Pass PHP variable to javascript/jquery for error checking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

Saw other examples close to this, but I seem to still be having issues. The issue is with the script for the third error checker below (#bid < #budm). The amount of the bid field cannot be lower than the amount of the set budget, which #budm should be storing. Pulling a value for #budm from database related to the post id, using php. trying to pass that variable into a js error checker that compares the hidden input field (id="budm"), which stores the php variable, against a user entered input field (id="bid"). Seems to work on random. For instance, on a post where the value of $budgetmin was 400, most entries under 400 were not accepted (which is good), but for some reason, the value '9' was.

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$cid = $current_user->ID;
$cwd = str_replace('wp-admin','',getcwd());
$post = get_post($pid);
$budgetmin = get_post_meta($pid, 'budget_start', true); ?>

<input type="hidden" id="budm" value="<?php echo $budgetmin; ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">

function check_submits()
{

if( jQuery("#days_done").val().length == 0 ) 
{
    alert("<?php _e('Error text3'); ?>");
    return false;   
}

if( jQuery("#bid").val().length == 0 ) 
{
    alert("<?php _e('Error text2'); ?>");
    return false;   
}

if (jQuery('#bid').val() < jQuery('#budm').val()) 
{
     alert("<?php _e('Error text'); ?>");
     return false;
}

return true;
}


</script>

<input type="text" name="bid" id="bid" class="bid_field" value="<?php echo     $bid; ?>" size="10" /> 

<input class="green_btn grey" style="font-size: 20px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-weight: 400;" id="submits_crt" type="submit" name="bid_now_reverse" value="<?php echo "Submit"; ?>" />
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, check the browser console for any errors. Then check if jQuery is use in *no-conflict mode* or not.

Comment: Okay, you say it's questionable, but what exactly happens when you run the code?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! So...

- $budgetmin = 100
- User enters 10 into #bid input field
- Error check runs correctly.

-User then resubmits an amount of 50 into #bid
- Error check fails and value of 50 is excepted.

Comment: @RyanVollmer do you mean 'value of 50 is **accepted**'?  As dekkard suggested, check the console for errors.  Post the code for #bid being submitted.

Comment: Yea, accepted. It's obviously way too early. Will have the console code posted here asap. :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again. @dekkard the only text in the console is: jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:5 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

That seems to always display, even without the code for the issue i am having. no-conflict mode does not appear to be on. I re-wrote the above code using 'jQuery' instead of '$' just in case.

Comment: @Don'tPanic  the additional code has been posted. The form submits are at the bottom of my question along with some additional information.

Comment: How is ```check_submits() ``` called?

Comment: Thanks but as @dekkard says, we still can't see how #bid is submitted, how  `check_submits()` is called.  The code you've posted seems fine so what we can't see must be relevant.  [Here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/bxwdoweu/) with a simplified version of your code working fine.

Comment: Thanks guys....I really appreciate your patience and help. checksubmits is being called via:

    @Don'tPanic

 <form onsubmit="return check_submits();" method="post" action="<?     php echo get_permalink($pid); ?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="control_id" value="<?php echo base64_encode($pid); ?>" />

Comment: @Don'tPanic also, on the jsFiddle.... just tried putting the number 9 in as a bid and it produced the messaged "All OK, bid is over budget". Entering 400 produced the correct response of "Bid is lower than budget"

Comment: You're quite right.  I found the problem and posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.val()` returns a string, not a number.  The test is comparing the 2 values as strings, which is not what you want and doesn't behave as you expect.

You need to cast your values as numbers before the test will work.  If you know they're always going to be integers, you could use:

```
var bid=parseInt(jQuery('#bid').val()),
    budm=parseInt(jQuery('#budm').val());

if (bid < budm) {
    alert("Bid is lower than budget");
}
```

You could use parseFloat() if the inputs could be floats.

[Here's a jsFiddle showing this working](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/ucg6jo42/).

Comment: Trying this as soon as I get home! Thank you! -Ryan

Comment: thank you so much for the help!! This solution worked. I greatly appreciate it!!